# Verb subcategoriztion - intransitive, transitive, ditransitive, Verb with a complement clause

Tags: grammar, verbs

I'm trying to avoid building grammatically incorrect sentences in some small toy grammar I'm building.
I find subcategorization of verbs  bit confusing.
Can there be more then one classification per verb?

Can anyone please help me with the subcategorization of these verbs:

```
wanted
kissed
understood
pickled
thought
sighed
perplexed
worked
eating
```

It will help me figure out this issue.
Thanks!

Comment: There can indeed be many subcategorizations per verb. And some of these are not subcategories of verbs but of clause types and constructions. _Kissed,_ for instance, can be reciprocal or reflexive - _She kissed him; He kissed her; They kissed each other; They kissed._

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that please

Comment: I read in that all of these should fit these some of these 4 categories - that is why I'm confused.

Comment: @Araucaria - you thought of that before I did.

Comment: Is there any rule or a method to identify these subcategories or features? Is there some dictionary for that? Thanks!

Comment: You could do a search on [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) and see what kinds of complementation you see (having checked that the examples are examples of verbs!). Not going to catch everything though.